# How to sort HashMap by key order?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I would like to have a duplicate copy of an entire hashmap that is sorted by key. The hashmap is of type HashMap. Below is what I did.

```
SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(unsortedap.keySet());
        for (String key : keys) {
            String value = unsortedMap.get(key);
            // I have noticed that here the key values are in order
            // How do I copy these ordered values to a hashmap?
}
```

The values seem to be sorted after using TreeSet, however, I am not sure of what to do now. How can I get these values into a new hashmap?

Comment: `new TreeMap(unsortedMap)` should work.

Comment: It does not seem to have the new order. After I added the code snippet I printed out the hashmap values and they were the same still. The sortedSet is sorted, but I could not cast that to a Hashmap

Comment: @portfoliobuilder An HashMap doesn't retain a "logical" order such as alphabetical for the key. In fact it has no order. You can use TreeMap instead.

Comment: Ok, so this I could use an example of. I have not used a TreeMap before (first time hearing about this)

Comment: Actually you shoul only specify itz type on creation. From then on use either Map or SortedMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is just to put the key-value pairs into a TreeMap. Normally this will be ordered by key in default comparator order. If you need custom ordering you can construct the TreeMap with a custom Comparator which implements your preferred ordering.

Instead of your code, just use:

```
SortedMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(unsortedMap);
```

You can be sure a TreeMap will use the same ordering as a TreeSet if only because a TreeSet uses a TreeMap with null values 'under the hood' for its implementation anyway.

Comment: I will accept this answer, and do some research on SortedMaps and TreeMaps. Thanks!